# Can't find element to click on it /send keys in selenium with Java

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium

I'm new in this forum and this is actually my first time ever coding

in the code i have this part:

```
md-input-container class="md-default-theme md-input-invalid">
label for="input_4">Email</label>
input name="emailField" type="email" ng-model="email" ng-change="resetValidity()" auto-focus="" validate-email="" required="" class="ng-pristine md-input ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" id="input_4" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" style="">
!-- ngIf: forgot_password.emailField.$invalid && forgot_password.$submitted -->
/md-input-container>
```

the ID everytime i open a session get a different number. 
i try this:

```
WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='emailField']"));
emailField.click();
emailField.sendKeys("aa@aa");
```

can be reach also in the URL: "ocloud.optitex.com"
go to "forgot password" i'm trying to find the email field there , click on it and send keys

but nothing happen. i get this error:

> No such Element Exception , unable to locate element.

will appreciate any help regarding how i can click on the field and send keys.

Comment: is your element in iframe ?

Comment: nop. not in iframe. - i forgot to add one line to the code- editing.

Comment: can you try this `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='emailField']")));  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='emailField']")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");` and let me know any issue

Comment: @N.P Did the Answers solve your Question? Let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: @narendra-rajput I got the same result , no such element exception ,Unable to locate element

Comment: can you share the url of site if possible

Comment: https://ocloud.optitex.com  > go to "forgot password"  i'm trying to find the email field there , click on it and send keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Implicit wait` in your code to give sufficient time to locate the element before it through exception

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();    
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://ocloud.optitex.com/#/login/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[contains(.,'Forgot Password?')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='emailField']")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[contains(.,'Reset Password')]")).click();
```

Comment: no the F wasn't the problem . same result.  - but i will edit my question with the "F".

Comment: @N.P , Use updated code , same is working fine at my end

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath;

```
WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.xPath("//input[@name='emailField']"));
emailField.click();
emailField.sendKeys("aa@aa");
```

Comment: i got the same result , no such element exception ,Unable to locate element

Comment: Okay, can you try this xpath? "//md-input-container/input"

Comment: got this now:  unknown error: Element <input type="email" ng-model="cf.email" auto-focus="" required="" class="ng-pristine md-input ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" id="input_0" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" style=""> is not clickable at point (978, 435). Other element would receive the click: <md-input-container class="md-default-theme md-input-focused">...</md-input-container>

Comment: Can you edit your question with more source html code or url?